# Query regarding syntax used in a header file for socket programming

Tags: c, sockets

This is the piece of the code I copied from one of the header file for socket programming.

```
/* Structure describing an Internet socket address.  */
struct sockaddr_in
  {
    __SOCKADDR_COMMON (sin_);
    in_port_t sin_port;                 /* Port number.  */
    struct in_addr sin_addr;            /* Internet address.  */

    /* Pad to size of `struct sockaddr'.  */
    unsigned char sin_zero[sizeof (struct sockaddr) -
                           __SOCKADDR_COMMON_SIZE -
                           sizeof (in_port_t) -
                           sizeof (struct in_addr)];
  };
```

I can understand declaration of sin_port and sin_addr. but what is __SOCKADDR_COMMON in_) is here. I can't understand this syntax? Kindly explain. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There exists the macro definition:

```
#define __SOCKADDR_COMMON(sa_prefix) \
  sa_family_t sa_prefix##family
```

so `__SOCKADDR_COMMON (sin_);` actually expands to `sa_family_t sin_family;`

The way this happens is that the macro takes the parameter sa_prefix and uses the `##` operator to concatenate (join) them. The result is that you have a new variable `sin_family` which is declared with type `sa_family_t` in the struct.

Here's more info on macros and the [C Preprocessor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor)

Comment: i can't understand , what datatype  sa_prefix and sin_? what actually they represent? And is __SOCKADDR_COMMON is a function?

Answer (score 0):

It is a macro defined somwhere else.
It might be defined as

```
#define __SOCKADDR_COMMON(sa_prefix) \
  sa_family_t sa_prefix##family
```

expanding that, the struct would look like

```
struct sockaddr_in
  {
    sa_family_t sin_family;
    in_port_t sin_port;      
 ...
```

**DO NOT** copy this structure into your code. You are supposed to include the header file for your system that declares struct sockaddr_in.

Comment: What is this ## in second line?

Comment: It is the prerocessor token concatenation operator. See e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Token_concatenation

Answer (score 0):

`__SOCKADDR_COMMON()` will be a `#define` macro that expands a set of common fields to be used in all structures