# C - What does this line mean in this struct?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Query regarding syntax used in a header file for socket programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829435/query-regarding-syntax-used-in-a-header-file-for-socket-programming)

```
struct sockaddr_un 
{
   __SOCKADDR_COMMON (sun_);
   char sun_path[108];/* Path name. */ 
};
```

`__SOCKADDR_COMMON (sun_);`
I want to know what this line means,

Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829435/query-regarding-syntax-used-in-a-header-file-for-socket-programming

Comment: grep -Rl SOCKADDR_COMMON /usr/include/*

Comment: Please, use the search functionality of SO. The search field is located in the top right corner of the web page. Searching for `__SOCKADDR_COMMON` reveals several similar questions.

Answer (score 4):

`_SOCKADDR_COMMON` is a macro.

```
#define __SOCKADDR_COMMON(p)  sa_family_t p##family
```

So this call :

```
__SOCKAXDDR_COMMON(sun_)
```

will expand to :

```
sa_family_t sun_family;
```

Comment: Thanks, i should have noticed that it's a macro.